# How to create multiboot persistent USB drive

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub, bootloader

a) I am experiencing a problem with attempt to install Fedora directly to USB (persistent install).My USB is 2TB in size i wonder if its a hardware problem or fedora does not support large USB’s?

B) However, what im trying to achieve is to have a persistent USB drive with multiboot(persumably grub interface with EFI boot support).

c) what is the best option to achieve this.Do i have to create additional partition? a) during fedora setup for Later windows setup b) install fedora as normal and use fdisk or similar latet and allocate space for windows boot partition?

D) How to set-up multiboot grub prompt( Windows + Fedora ) if i install fedora first?

Comment: What kind of usb are you using? Brand that is. Would be good to add to the question.

Comment: What is the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: When i set up Fedora i choose a USB drive as a destination drive where Fedora will be installed (without automatic partition preference) ,when creating boot drive partition ,installation crashes and it seams that it cant to USB drive.I wonder maybe 2TB USB is naturally too large ,for instance android 6.0 supports only 256gb USB. Or is it harware error in USB micrcontroller ?

Comment: I have (U Disk) 2TB usb pendrive

Comment: I have also tried automatic partitioning preference in Fedora setup,but installation also fails with same result(Can’t partition USB drive)

Answer (score 0):

"I have (U Disk) 2TB usb pendrive"

Then it is almost certainly a fake if it is a flash drive!
https://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/-fake-usb-flash-memory-drives

Comment: It certainly is.Thanks for information!